# Installed App Sizes Vs Appstore app sizes

Tags: ios, app-store

Here is a question that had been bothering me. The other day I checked my wife's phone and pinterest app was eating up 2 GB of space while the actual app in the appstore is 26.8 MB. I know there must be user / log / crash data that is dumped in its apps document directory but that got me thinking how many other apps on her phone had large amount of user data stored compared to what the app size is in appstore.

So here are my questions of how to do all this using objectiveC

1. Sample Xcode [iHasApp](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ihasapp) display's all the available apps installed on a device. Is there a way I check how much space they are taking in GB/MB etc?
2. Is there a way I can go query that app build size in appstore and tell the user hey its only X MB in appstore?
3. I know I can get to all the app installed on a device is there a way I can check when was an app last launched or used by a user?
4. Can I check how much space photo / video and music is taking up?

What I am trying do in the end is to see if I can make an app that shows user what they got installed on their device and make some informed decisions themselves.

So far all I am able to find is how to check total used and free space on a device and get a list of all apps installed.

Comment: Are you talking about jailbroken devices?

Comment: You want to write an app that does what is already covered under settings-->general-->usage?

Comment: @jrturton - usage doesn't show when was the app last used or what the app size is in appstore. It only shows app sizes on the device from large to small. With my app I would like to do tons of filters / sorts, if i can

Comment: @SamB - I am looking for an answer to Point 4 , without doing the calculation manually - one file at a time, did you have any luck with this ?

Answer (score 2):

> Sample Xcode iHasApp display's all the available apps installed on a device. Is there a way I check how much space they are taking in GB/MB etc?

No. The APIs being used by iHasApp can only be used to check whether selected applications are present -- basically, all you get to ask "is ThisApp installed?", and you can build up a **partial** list of installed applications by running that check for a large number of common applications.

There is no way to get launch or disk usage information for other applications. I'm not sure last launch is even tracked at all by the device.

With this in mind, most of your other questions are irrelevant. It is not possible to do what you're after from an iOS application.

Comment: even though I have been making ios apps for a while now, I still can't tell what can or cannot be done. Its always a mystery. The other day I saw an app called iCleaner to delete and free up space and I thought that should not be allowed yet its in appstore. So I had to ask