# Detect app installation with StoreKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, storekit

iOS6 introduced StoreKit framework which is designated for interacting with the AppStore from within the app.
I easily managed to direct the user to a specific app, the question is how can I detect whether the user actually installed the app I redirected him to?

Comment: Do you mean from a different app?

Comment: yes. The same way Facebook app uses to advertise different apps

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done by calling `-canOpenURL:` on `UIAplication` object like this:

```
NSURL *appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb:"];
BOOL appInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appURL];
```

But you need to know what URL scheme does the second app open. It is declared in Info.plist file by the app developer.

Comment: This is not very helpful and I'll explain why - Right after installing the app (using SKStoreProductViewController), the delegated is called (before the app actually completes installation process). So the call for 'canOpenURL' happens too soon and thus returns false.

Comment: Your argument is invalid. That code works. It detects if the app is installed. If the app is not installed (yet), it returns false. I don't know about any other way to detect that. Just check multiple times or use timer every 5 seconds or something.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source framework called "iHasApp" avaiable that can detect installed apps.
Git Repository: [iHasApp](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp)

Comment: I looked into it, iHasApp doesn't work. Its a pre-list of "some" not all apps. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152049/installed-app-sizes-vs-appstore-app-sizes

Comment: You can't get a list of all of the apps! There is no non-private API for doing so.